# How to use variables in lambda expression inside jquery (MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two variables in jquery, one to get the client detail and the second to get the data from the model. It goes like :

```
var office  = $("#<%=Html.GetIDFor(m=>m.Archive.OfficeID)%>").val();

var offsets = '<%= Model.CountryOfficeList.Where(p=>p.Id == Model.Archive.OfficeID).Select(p=>p.UTCOffset).First()%>';
```

The code is to get the offsets depending on the officeID. Now i want to get the offset of the office selected on the client side so that i can use it for further processing.

I am not able to use it like:

```
 var offsets = '<%= Model.CountryOfficeList.Where(p=>p.Id == **office**).Select(p=>p.UTCOffset).First()%>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Javascript variable on the serverside. You have to send it thru AJAX or do a post/get request.

Comment: I dint want to create another instance of the model to get the data I want. Thats the reason I tried out this way.. So finally there is no go ?

Comment: Whats on the clientside is not available for the server/ASP.NET. But its really easy to add an AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks Simon! I know its easy. But for me such a call would be costly. Just wanted to try some easy go :)

Comment: is it possible to get the select list model items as a list to jquery variable ?

Comment: jQuery("#Selectlist").val() <- Give you the selected value. If you want the values from the select list to go into a variable use:
var obj = new Array(); jQuery.each(jQuery("#Selectlist").children(),function(index,item){ obj.push(jQuery(item).val());})
Its diffrent question now, mark this as answered if it was useful and start other question insteed.